# I want to apply encryption and decryption on app.config in window form application on client side

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, app-config, password-encryption

I'm new in window form application and deploying my first application in c# entity frame using data model .edmx.
the problem is that when deploying application the connection string can easily read and any can read my credential.

for this purpose made up a separate project that encrypt config file and runs successfully on my development machine but i'm getting error on client side like
"failed to decry-pt using provider 'dataprotectionconfigurationprovider.key not valid for use in specifed state."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the key in your config by using aspnet_regiis.exe. That works  Even if the application is not an ASP.NET app. 1. Rename the app.config in your directory to web.config (don't worry, this is just temporary, we'll rename it back later). 
2. Go to the command prompt. 
3. Type the following (replace the last argument with the path containing the directory to the app.config, currently renamed to web.config.  For example, if the full path to the web config is "C:\documents and settings\bob\projects\myproject\web.config", you would use "C:\documents and settings\bob\projects\myproject")

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings"

4. You should see it say "Succeeded!"
5. Reopen the web.config, it should look something like this:




     
     
       
         
         
           Rsa Key
         
         
           rUmEA8h02uMZ5M4uEVtL+5M/UvPuyJ4UJz5d/Pd4h4jpFPGVf29ha4d+BMt/iOupVisXDxuZY1jzyc6O0ZixGcCkZqbynwKjouVANQVWUnDgIFgVap2ohsxjblAMtWHTUWDlL0ST5tqSVHNQE+r9G59Bnrp5HkuU3Eg09/8j6Jo=
         
       
     
     
       U2JEHzJ+WjSdlocT00cC9TE3+Dn3v7xE1RwX7bKAPuISO2f3hm18MZHnm1hXEBlnDS6iBNRPN87+BJJvZXYz+Sis/ZD4xBZEP4jBG2F8tqlLUbagv3W4epbuTSp2aalb5rdcBoycdIzSj2CApOzSaSKkMDvZrX8yoJI9RfuGnOWmNa4bncHkUEDvWq+uCK/8uaQ48J5uRoq7O0YgIe9jDg==
6. Lastly, rename the file from web.config to app.config. 
   From here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3b5a1d1f-aa57-40d8-8607-fee0b2a8a6db/protect-appconfig-file-or-encrypt

Comment: Could not covert 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" E:\Nabeel WorkSpace\Projects\ATMS1\ATMS\Web.Config

this will shows all asp.net registration Options

Comment: Failed to decrypt using provider 'RasProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message form the provider : The RSA key Container could not be opened.

Any help